# Show that the following matrix is nonsingular

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, matrix-rank

$z$ is a vector in $R^n$. Given the following functions:

$c_i(z): R^n\to R$

$c(z) = (c_1(z),\dots,c_m(z))^T$

$A(z)^T = [\nabla c_i (z)]_{i\in [m]}$, where $[m] = \{1,2,\dots,m\}$

And $A(z)^T$ has full column rank.

We construct a matrix $Z$, whose columns are a basis of $Nul\ A(z)$.

Please prove 
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}{A\left(z\right)} \\\\{Z^{T}}\end{array}\right]
$$
is invertible (nonsingular).

Let me know if you have any puzzles about the problem itself.

Comment: Have you ever seen a proof of the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: Yes, I have looked up the proof.

Comment: Well then :-) I'll let you answer your own question and collect all the upvotes.

Comment: But what I get is only $rank(A(z)) = m$, $rank(Z) = n-m$

Comment: This is why I asked you to look at the proof, not at the theorem.

Comment: Oh, my god. I have looked up the proof according to your instructions, but I'm still in trouble. Hope you can help me!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100741/discussion-between-ben-and-arnaud-mortier).

Comment: Well, I've written an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any subspace $V$ of $\Bbb R^n$, you have a decomposition
$$\Bbb R^n=V\oplus V^\perp$$
In the present case, consider $V$ to be the row space of $A(z)$. Then by definition $V^\perp=\operatorname{Ker}A(z)$.

By construction, the rows of $A(z)$ are a basis of $V$ and the rows of $Z^T$ are a basis of $V^\perp$. Since $\Bbb R^n=V\oplus V^\perp$, it follows that the rows of the full matrix form a basis of $\Bbb R^n$, so that the matrix is non-singular.

Comment: What does $^⊥$ mean?

Comment: @Ben It means the orthogonal subspace to $V$, the set of all vectors whose scalar product with any element of $V$ is zero.

Comment: Why do we have, for any subspace  of $ℝ_n$, we have a decomposition? What theorem does this rely on?

Comment: @Ben It is well-known, you will find it in any textbook. You first show that by Gaussian elimination the dimension of $V^\perp$ is $n-\dim V$, and then you show separately that $V$ and $V^\perp$ are in direct sum.

Comment: All right. Thanks.